# Why would my keystore get a different password digest from what it is expecting?

Tags: java, security, keystore, wss4j

I'm using WSS4J to sign a soap message. When the WSSecSignature is being built I get the following error:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

The error specifically happens here:

```
sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
```

I have triple checked that I am using the correct password, it is identical. If I change it for a different password I get a different error about not being able to access keystore. After looking at the code, a copy of which can be seen here:

```
/*
 * Check the integrity of the recovered key by concatenating it with
 * the password, digesting the concatenation, and comparing the
 * result of the digest operation with the digest provided at the end
 * of <code>protectedKey</code>. If the two digest values are
 * different, throw an exception.
 */

md.update(passwdBytes);
Arrays.fill(passwdBytes, (byte)0x00);
passwdBytes = null;
md.update(plainKey);
digest = md.digest();
md.reset();
for (i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
    if (digest[i] != protectedKey[SALT_LEN + encrKeyLen + i]) {
        throw new UnrecoverableKeyException("Cannot recover key");
    }
}
```

It seems when the given password is being hashed and compared to the passwdBytes variable, it gets a different result and so it throws an error. I'm not sure what I've done wrong to get this result?

Comment: Does the key entry have a password of its own?

Comment: The key was stored in a pfx, which was password protected. Then I moved it to a .jks with some certificates. The password for the jks is different to the .pfx password. When I used the keytool to move it did it keep the original password?

Comment: It seems wss4j is using the default cryptographic provider of the JDK. It does not work with all types of PKCS12, specially if they were built with bouncycastle ( i do not know why). I suggest to repack the PFX ( create a new one and import the key) or force wss4j to use bouncycastle